# Using a base class for an integration test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

My base class for an integration test:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseIntegrationTest
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseIntegrationTest()
    {
        _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnectionTest");
    }

    [ClassInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        InsertTestData();
    }

    public void InsertTestData()
    {
        _dbContext.Users.Add(new User { Name = "John Doe" });
    }
}
```

Here's a test class that inherits from `BaseIntegrationTest`:

```
[TestClass]
public class UserRepositoryTests : BaseIntegrationTest
{
    // how to lose this method here and use the one in the BaseIntegrationTest?
    //[ClassInitialize]
    //public static void Setup(TestContext context)
    //{
    //  BaseIntegrationTest test = new BaseIntegrationTest();
    //  test.InsertTestData();
    //}

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetUser()
    {
        Filter f = new Filter()
        {
            Name = "John Doe"
        };

        UserRepository fr = new UserRepository(_dbContext);
        var result = fr.GetUser(f);

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Any(x => x.Name == "John Doe"));
    }
}
```

The method decorated with the `[ClassInitialize]` attribute in the `BaseIntegrationTest` never gets executed, and because of that, my tests fail. No data gets inserted into the database.

But if I uncomment the `public static void Setup(TestContext context)` in the `UserRepositoryTests` it works.

I have a few more repositories I want to test. And I want the data being inserted into the database being done in the base class so that I can run all the tests without recreating the database for every repository I want to test.

Converting `public void Initialize()` into `public static void Initialize(TestContext context)` doesn't work either. The `Initialize()` wont get executed/called.

Am I missing something? Or are these limitations of unit test/integration test? I'm pretty new to unit testing/integration testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Will the same approach that was used for `[TestInitialize]` work with
>   `[ClassInitialize]` in a base class?
>
> Not exactly, if you create a `[ClassInitialize]` attributed method in
>   the base class it won’t ever get called unless you explicitly call it
>   at the beginning of your derived test classes `ClassInitialize`
>   method; which of course is nowhere near as nice as the above approach.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/archive/2008/05/16/using-a-base-class-for-your-unit-test-classes.aspx

Later on it describes how to do initialisation before any methods in your inheriting class:

> How can I create an initialization method that will run before any
>   class initialization methods in my test project?
>
> Building on the common base class approach described above you could
>   simply add a static constructor to your base class and either perform
>   the initialization there or call the method that will perform the
>   desired initialization.  The resulting base class might look like
>   this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestBase
{
    static TestBase()
    {
        s_log = new StringBuilder();
        Log.AppendLine("TestBase.ctor()");
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void BaseTestInit()
    {
        Log.AppendLine("TestBase.BaseTestInit()");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void BaseTestCleanup()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Log.ToString());
    }

    public static StringBuilder Log
    {
        get { return s_log; }
    }

    static StringBuilder s_log;
}
```

Comment: You've got my upvote but I'd put an extract from linked source, in case link will be broken in future.

Comment: If I call `InsertTestData()` from the static constructor, than I have to make `InsertTestData()` static too, and all other methods that I call from the static constructor. This worked, but I question it's elegance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While this pattern works with nunit, it appears it doesn't work with mstest, since the ClassInitializeAttribute cannot not be inherited.

One work around is to do your initialization in the constructor of your base class.

Something like:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseIntegrationTest
{
    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseIntegrationTest()
    {
        _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnectionTest");
         InsertTestData();
    }

    public void InsertTestData()
    {
        _dbContext.Users.Add(new User { Name = "John Doe" });
    }
}
```

You could add a static flag to prevent it running every test:

```
[TestClass]
public class BaseIntegrationTest
{
    private static bool _testsInitialized = false;

    protected readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public BaseIntegrationTest()
    {
        if(!_testsInitialized) {
            _dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext("DefaultConnectionTest");
             InsertTestData();
            _testsInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    public void InsertTestData()
    {
        _dbContext.Users.Add(new User { Name = "John Doe" });
    }
}
```

..pretty inelegant, but maybe more elegant than making static your ApplicationDbContext (and all other methods called from a static ctor)

Comment: That was my original approach, but the constructor gets executed on every test method that is being executed. And therefore inserting dublicate data, or at least trying to do so, because I have unique indices in the User table. It throws an error about it.

Comment: I edited the answer to provide a workaround for this - slightly more elegant than making ALL your methods / variables static

Comment: That will fail too because the whole base class seems to be 'reset' for every test method you run. So `_testsInitialized = true;` will actually never stay true. The next test method that is going to be executed, it will have it's default value which is false as how you have declared it. I must add that this is one of the things I've already tried.